# how to check if IE 5.5 is online

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, navigator, internet-explorer-5

I'm trying to check if browser has internet connection with javascript but I encountered some problems on IE 5.5

```
<script>
function checkConnection(){
           if(navigator.onLine === false){
               //document.execCommand("Stop");
               alert("No internet connection.");
               document.execCommand("Stop");
}
</script>
```

and:

```
<input type="submit" value="GO" name="whereTo" onclick="checkConnection();"  />
```

It seems that IE 5.5 doesn't have navigator.onLine property, how can I check for connection for IE 5.5?

Comment: You shouldn't want to be dealing with such outdated stuff I guess...

Comment: IE 5.5? That was released over 13 years ago! Do you *really* need to support it?

Comment: The internet was not yet invented in the time of Internet Explorer 5.5

Comment: Yes because customer has PDA which runs only IE 5.5 unfortunately
EDIT: Let me put it this way: i want to check at least network connection, it is not necessary to put it on internet :)

Comment: @user2902058 What are you going to do if they are online and if they are offline? (I doubt IE5.5 would support it anyway.)

Comment: IE5.5 is like a wide open door to viruses and worms come in...

Comment: Tell them to get a new phone?

Comment: Come on guys i know that this is bad case, but i'm trying to solve a problem anyway

Comment: @user2902058 Can you clarify *why* you want to test this?

Comment: I'm developing web application and in case wifi drops, you get message thad you don't havce connection

Comment: Have yourself some respect and drop IE5.5 support. First you need to learn to let go...

Comment: "*customer has PDA which runs only IE 5.5*" ... That's fine. Actually, if you've got someone paying you to work with IE5.5, then fair enough. However, it is important for both you and your customer to understand that IE5.5 is not supported and has not been for some time. Features you rely on may simply not exist. There's nothing wrong with accepting a job working on obsolete tech, but you should make sure you bill your time appropriately (ie charge him a lot more than normal), and make sure that expectations are not set too high on what you will be able to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Why not trying to send an AJAX request?
It won't check if you're strictly online, but it would tell you if you can reach something... Trying a couple of URLs might be enough...

```
function ajaxRequest(url) {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE 7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }  else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState !== 4 && xmlhttp.status !== 200) {
      alert("No internet connection.");
      document.execCommand("Stop");
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET",url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  return false;
}
```